# How to print a name in a Python list whose index corresponds to the number inputted by a user?

Tags: python

So if i had a list that's something like
`lista=[a,b,c,d,e]`

How would I ask the user to input a number that prints the letter of the corresponding index in the list?
For example , if the user enter the number 3 , the letter of index 3 in the list ie: 'd' would get printed?

Comment: Please post some code sample regarding what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the index you want and access the list using it.

In Python 3 use `input()`:

```
index = int(input("Enter your number") # transform to int
print(list[index]) # print item
```

While in Python 2 use `raw_input()`:

```
index = int(raw_input("Enter your number") # transform to int
print list[index] # print item
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I realized I simply wasn't converting it into int before.